# Querying against an array in Parse

Tags: php, parse-platform

This has been racking my brain all day and can't seem to find the answer anywhere, and was wondering if anybody could help.

I have a field in a table in Parse called keywords which is an array of keywords. On the front end of the web application there will be a search box which will search the table against the keywords.I then want to retrieve any records that match against the keywords that were passed in the query.

I am using the PHP SDK.

I have tried to use functions such as containsAll and containedIn but not had any joy.

Could anyone point me onto the right path.

Thanks!

Comment: you should have a keywords table, with word per row

Comment: Yeah that would make sense. Unfortunatley, this is an existing application so I am unable to change the structure :( Am I pretty much stuck in what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Keyword from client input is only one or multiple? If single input, you should use equalTo. All results must match=> containsAll, one of result match=>containedIn, but these 2 needs array. If array size is only one, containedIn is equal to containsAll and "equalTo this elemnt" on functionality.